# Roku: Change Overhang panel image size

Tags: roku, brightscript

The Roku [Overhang panel](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Overhang) allows for specicification of a logo (`logoUri`).

How do you set the size of the logo? The image asset I want to use is fairly large, and the Overhang widget is not scaling it down automatically.  I use this image asset other places in the app so I don't want to ship a smaller one in my zip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, you can't specify size of the logo. You have to provide not just one, but 3 images for SD, HD, and FHD using **uri_resolution_autosub** attribute if you want it to look neat in all resolutions.

Comment: What are the sizes supposed to be for those three images?